# Basic cash system in C++

Tags: c++, computer-science

In the below code, I've got some bugs and I don't know why it doesn't work.

I used a `fmod` to do the decimals but I got some bugs in the part where it gives you the 0.10 and 0.05 $ and most of the time I never get the good amount that I'm supposed to give back if there is.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int iAmount_due = { 0 };

    int iGiven_money = { 0 };

    int iMoney_back;

    iMoney_back = iGiven_money - iAmount_due;


    cout << "Enter the amount due please: " << endl;

    cin >> iAmount_due;

    cout << "Enter the amount given please: " << endl;

    cin >> iGiven_money;


    if (iGiven_money >= iAmount_due) {

       iMoney_back = iGiven_money - iAmount_due;

        cout << "We will give you : " << iMoney_back << " $ back" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No money back" << endl;

    }



    if (iMoney_back >= 100) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << iMoney_back % 100 << " x 100$" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 100$ bill" << endl;

    }



    if (iMoney_back >= 50) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << iMoney_back % 50 << " x 50$" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 50$ bill" << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 20) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << iMoney_back % 20 << " x 20$" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 20$ bill" << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 10) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << iMoney_back % 10 << " x 10$" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 10$ bill" << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 5) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << iMoney_back %  5  << " x 5$" << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 5$ bill" << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 0.25) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << fmod (iMoney_back, 0.25) << " x 0.25$ " << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 0.25$ " << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 0.10) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << fmod (iMoney_back, 0.10) << " x 0.10$ " << endl;

    }

    else {

        cout << "No 0.10$ " << endl;

    }


    if (iMoney_back >= 0.05) {

        cout << "You will receive: " << fmod (iMoney_back, 0.05) << " x 0.05$ " << endl;

    }


    else {

        cout << "No 0.05$ " << endl;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your input, expected output, and actual output to illustrate the problem?

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. Here you tried to write the whole thing at once, a big program to do everything, and it's not working and you don't know where the problem is. Start over, perhaps with a program that reports $0.05, and don't add more functionality until that works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

`int` holds only *integer* values. `0.05` is not an integer value. You might be tempted to use `double` values instead that probably work for your simple problem; however, they generally have rounding errors which is something you really do not want to have with currency values.

The better solution will be to still use integers. You would need to define `1` as the smallest possible unit (e.g. 1 cent), meaning that all your values will be in cent. You would need to write extra code to be able to enter and display values as dollars instead of cents.